# Trying to use GUI, having trouble adding buttons and labels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

The assignment is simple, all we need to do is have the code create a window with a red panel with a single button and label. Here is the code thus far as well as the tester class.
I got the label to display on the window, but its in a weird place. I cant get the button to display at all as well getting the background to display as red.

This is where I'm having trouble with the most:

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyCustomFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MyCustomFrame()
    {
        createComponents();
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

    }

private void createComponents()
    {
        JPanel panel=new createPanel();
        button=new JButton("Push Me");
        label=new JLabel("This is a label");
        add(button);
        add(label);
    }

private JButton button;
private JLabel label;
final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 800;

public void createPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        //button=new JButton("Push Me");
        //label=new JLabel("This is a label");

    }
public void createFrame()
    {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        add(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

And this is the tester class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyCustomFrameViewer
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MyCustomFrame frame = new MyCustomFrame();
      frame.setTitle("My first frame");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the panel to the frame instead of the label and button, and add the label and button to the panel...

```
private void createComponents()
{
    JPanel panel=new createPanel();
    add(panel);
    button=new JButton("Push Me");
    label=new JLabel("This is a label");
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(label);
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and make sure you are creating your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

*Some side notes...*

This scares me...

```
public void createFrame()
{
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    add(frame);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

You're trying to add a frame to a frame, which is an illegal operation in Swing, but thankfully, you're not actually calling it from what I can see.

Instead of using `setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);`, you may wish to use `pack` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You create the JPanel, panel, but add nothing to it, and then never add the panel to your JFrame. You should add your components to the JPanel, panel, and then add the panel object to your JFrame.

Note that a JPanel uses FlowLayout by default, and so it will more easily accept multiple other components without special add methods. The JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout which is slightly more complicated to use.

Answer (score 2):

See also the tips in comments in this example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

// Don't extend frame, just use an instance
//public class MyCustomFrame extends JFrame {
public class MyCustomFrame {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;
    private JPanel panel;
    // better to override the preferred size of the component of interest
    final int GAME_WIDTH = 300;
    final int GAME_HEIGHT = 100;

    public MyCustomFrame() {
        createComponents();
        // better to override the preferred size of the component of interest
        //setSize(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        // compilation error!  createPanel() does not return anything..
        //JPanel panel = new createPanel();
        createPanel();
        // create the frame!
        createFrame();
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        // creates a local instance
        //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel = new JPanel() {

            /* override the preferred size of the component of interest */
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT);
            }
        };
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        button = new JButton("Push Me");
        label = new JLabel("This is a label");
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
    }

    private void createFrame() {
        // create a local instance of a JFrame that goes out of scope at end
        // of method..
        //JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame = new JFrame("My first frame");
        // add the panel to the frame!
        frame.add(panel);
        // better to use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE
        //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // a good way to position a GUI
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        // this was trying to add a JFrame to another JFrame
        //add(frame);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public final JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyCustomFrame myFrame = new MyCustomFrame();
                JFrame frame = myFrame.getFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```